# Entity Framework - Share Transactions across Bounded Contexts

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, dbcontext, bounded-contexts

I am working on a very large application with over 100 modules, and almost 500 tables in the database. We are converting this application to WPF/WCF using Entity Framework 4.2 Code First. Our database is SQL Anywhere 11. Because of the size of the database, we are using an approach similar to Bounded DbContexts, as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx by Julie Lerman.
Each of our modules creates its own DbContext, modeling only the subset of the database that it needs.

However, we have run into a serious problem with the way DbContexts are created. Our modules are not neatly self-contained, nor can they be. Some contain operations that are called from several other modules. And when they are, they need to participate in transactions started by the calling modules. (And for architectural reasons, DTC is not an option for us.) In our old ADO architecture, there was no problem passing an open connection from module to module in order to support transactions.

I've looked at various DbContext constructor overloads, and tried managing the transaction from EntityConnection vs. the StoreConnection, and as far as I can tell, there is no combination that allows ModuleA to begin a transaction, call a function in ModuleB, and have ModuleB's DbContext participate in the transaction.

It comes down to two simple things:

Case 1. If I construct DbContextB with DbContextA's EntityConnection, DbContextB is not built with its own model metadata; it reuses DbContextA's metadata. Since the Contexts have different collections of DbSets, all ModuleB's queries fail. (The entity type is not a part of the current context.)

Case 2. If I construct DbContextB with ModuleA's StoreConnection, DbContextB does not recognize the StoreConnection's open transaction at the EntityConnection level, so EF tries to start a new transaction when ModuleB calls SaveChanges(). Since the database connection in fact has an open transaction, this generates a database exception. (Connection does not support parallel transactions.)

Is there any way to 1) force DbContextB to build its own model in Case 1, or 2) get DbContextB's ObjectContext to respect its StoreConnection's transaction state in Case 2?

(By the way, I saw some encouraging things in the EF6 alpha, but after testing it out, found the only difference was that I could create DbContextB on an open connection. But even then, the above 2 problems still exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try use the `TransactionScope` object to manage this task for you. As long as all of your `DbContexts` use the same **connection string** (not connection object) the transaction should not try to enlist MS-DTC.